# grep or C code to parse log file?

Tags: c, parsing, awk, grep

I have a log file I want to parse

I only need the first two fields (separated by space)

sample line from the log file:

```
1362960460.697 19 27.197.12.76 TCP_MISS/404 339 GET http://what-ever-server.com/what-ever-file - DIRECT/22.22.22.22 text/html
```

The first field should be without the numbers after the "."

I thought I could  do it with C but it's gonna be so complicated having a pointer to trace every character to check if it's space or "."
so I saw in some posts here that grep can do the job
but the fields in my file don't have a fixed length

Should I do it in C? or is there an option in grep that can let me parse

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what awk is for.

```
cat logfile | awk '{print $1 " " $2}' | sed 's_\.[0-9]*__g'
```

You print the first and second fields of each line with `awk`. Then you match the decimal places and remove them using `sed`.

Comment: +1 but you are using three processes where one would be sufficient. (Not a problem when parsing a single file)

Comment: I'm gonna do this for thousands of lines in the same file.. I think one of the answers bellow uses only awk

Comment: UUOC and UUO sed. Just use awk alone or sed alone.

Answer (score 4):

To get the first 2 fields of a file use `awk` (included in all unix or linux distributions)

```
awk '{split($1,a,"."); print a[1], $2}' logfile
```

Explanation:

- `split` function splits the first token (`$1`) into array `a` based on separator `.`
- `print a[1], $2` prints the two values based on the output field separator, which is by default space

A simpler way (assuming the first field is a number), is to use the `int` function:

```
 awk '{print int($1), $2}' logfile
```

Comment: awk is included in all UNIX or linux distributions, not most. It is a standard UNIX tool like grep, sed, diff, etc.

Comment: The simpler way you posted would fail if the first field can contain non-digits before the ".". See what I mean abut having to rely on the posted sample input being representative? All the OP said is that there's digits AFTER the ".".

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat file
1362960460.697 19 27.197.12.76 TCP_MISS/404 339 GET http://what-ever-server.com/what-ever-file - DIR
ECT/22.22.22.22 text/html

$ awk -F'[ .]' '{print $1,$3}' file
1362960460 19

$ sed 's/\([^.]\)\.[^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1 \2/' file
1362960460 19
```

Comment: The pitfall with using the field separator like this, is that if the first field lacks a decimal part, then `$3` will be 27 instead of 19.

Comment: And is that the case? I suspect not. At some point we have to rely on the OP posting representative sample input and if "."s can be absent from the first field or can be present in the second field or if one of the fields can have spaces inside quotes or anything else then that would be obviously important for them to show.

Answer (score 0):

BSD version (i.e. OSX)

```
cat logfile | awk '{print $1, $2}' | sed -e 's;\.*;;g'
```

Comment: That sed command says "find the first string on each line that starts with any sequence of zero or more repetitions (*) of any character (.) and remove it" so it will delete all text on every output line.

Comment: @EdMorton not in the bsd sed. Anyway I'll recheck tomorrow on my Mac

Comment: It'd got nothing to do with bsd or anything else. You're specifying a BRE of ".*" which means exactly what I said in any tool on any platform. It CANNOT mean anything else - it's as basic as it comes.

Comment: @EdMorton. You are right, it must be ascaped, actually it was, but it was deleted byt comment editor.